# PHP/CSS - Prevent a div from displaying if

Tags: php, css, html

I've nearly finished a new WordPress theme, my first.  There is a bit of custom code and unfortunately I am fairly new to PHP.

http://www.designated.net.au/testbed/wordpress/

As you can see there is a "spotlight" area for sticky posts.  But there are no sticky posts at the moment and every post is displaying in there.  When a post is made sticky it will display in there on its own.

What I would like to do is make it so the entire spotlight area doesn't display if there are no sticky posts.  I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Can you provide the php code behind this site?

Comment: Post some code so we may help you.. You can use http://pastie.org or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks guys.  This is the code I want to hide: http://pastie.org/4797229

Comment: offtopic but your remix is awesome ;)

Comment: Thank you very muchly!  If you like that check out my sets.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the `visible: hidden` CSS property of the div to hide it, or `display:none`. You just need to check if there is any sticky post to display.

```
<?php
    query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts')));
    // $nbrStickyPost = something 
    $stickyPost = ""

    if($nbrStickyPost === 0) {
        $stickyPost = " style=\"display:none;\""
    }

    echo "<div id=\"spotlight-feature\"", $stickyPost, ">";
?>

<div id="spotlight-feature-top">
<!-- [...] -->

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- [...] -->
```

This code will add the display:none CSS property to your div if the nbrStickyPost var is 0. I would need to see some of the query_posts() and have_posts() functions to really determine nbrStickyPost.

Comment: Oh inside the echo, I see.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I think I implemented it correctly but `stickyPost = ""` gives me a parse error.

Comment: Well, as I said, it depends on your actual PHP code, the vars are of course different for you but it's just an example of what you could add to do what you want.

You need to add the `display:none` property to your div when there are no post. There should be a var somewhere in the code with the count. That's the one you have to look for, and you also have to find the right div to hide. Just post your code if you want some more help there.

Comment: Oh ok.  I have to find the var.

Comment: Mistake on my part, it's $stickyPost instead of stickyPost. Haven't been doing PHP since a while. Just edited my original post.

Comment: I'm knackered and I need to go to bed so I'll pursue it in the morning.  Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: No problem. I just took a little look at your code, you're almost done. You will need to do your query_posts() function before the beginning of the div to check for the post count. I will edit my original answer to fit your code, give me a sec.

Comment: Here it is. Everything depends on the count now, would need the other 2-3 functions code to see how to do it. If the posts are all in an array, you could use count(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
;
If it's from a sql query, you could use mysql_num_rows(). And don't forget the "$" before your vars like I've done in my original code (which you actually pasted).

Comment: `if($nbrStickyPost === 0) {` gives the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /nfs/c05/h02/mnt/75451/domains/designated.net.au/html/testbed/wordpress/wp-content/themes/spotlight/header.php on line 107`

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough to understand your last comment.  Can you explain it in layman's terms?

Comment: I have resigned myself to the fact that to understand this and do it properly I'll have to learn PHP.  I can't really release a theme without knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: As I said, the $nbrStickyPost must be defined depending on the rest of your code (functions). But ya, the best for you would still be to learn PHP. From my point of view, it's a really easy language anyway and it helps a lot understanding programmation in general because PHP is derived from C++.

Comment: Ah I see.  Yeah you're right, I'll keep looking in to it.  Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: @Stephen O'Flynn About your edit, commas are faster than dots when using `echo`. It's faster to run multiple instances of `echo` than concatening. See http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=27423.0 and http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/output-in-php/. You're right about the parenthesis however.